# AndEngine: how to remove startup default activity screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, andengine

im trying to make example game using AndEngine, using simple code:

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

    static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0));
        return scene;
    }
}
```

but i found a strange behaviour: when the application starts, in the first moment it shows something like default android activity screen with titlebar and dark background, just for a moment, and then starts my activity with green background as it must be. How can i remove this startup thing?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your AndroidManifest.xml file.

In application:
Remove android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

In activity:
Add android:screenOrientation ="landscape"
or add android:screenOrientation ="portrait"

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that i had

screenOrientation =landscape|sensor,

made it :

screenOrientation =landscape,

and the default application screen disappeared.